# Store return value of function in reference C++

Tags: c++, reference, return-value

Is it valid to store the return value of an object in a reference?

```
class A { ... };
A myFunction()
{
    A myObject;
    return myObject;
} //myObject goes out of scope here

void mySecondFunction()
{
    A& mySecondObject = myFunction();
}
```

Is it possible to do this in order to avoid copying myObject to mySecondObject? myObject is not needed anymore and should be exactly the same as mySecondObject so it would in theory be faster just to pass ownership of the object from one object to another. (This is also possible using boost shared pointer but that has the overhead of the shared pointer.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is not allowed to bind the temporary to a non-const reference, but if you make your reference const you will extend the lifetime of the temporary to the reference, see [this Danny Kalev post about it](http://web.archive.org/web/20080221123313/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=199).

In short:

```
const A& mySecondObject = myFunction();
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why this is not allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm guessing that the reason is that allowing a non-const reference would mean that the compiler would be required to determine when the reference is re-assigned. I reckon that this is normally considered part of dynamic scope analysis and not used in the C++ standard. In the const case, on the other hand, only the static lifetime of the reference needs to be determined. This analysis is probably already required in other cases and was therefore deemed acceptable.

Comment: One can also note that this is a pretty simplistic pointer tracking feature, and that one could imagine a more advanced system. But in general I believe that C++ wants to avoid that problem and delegate it to the programmer instead. That's what smart pointers are for.

Comment: Your link is broken. I've found another [link](http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=30-C-Tips-in-30-Days-Tip-28-the-lifetime-of-a-temporary-object-bound-to-a-reference) but it looks incomplete.

Comment: @renadeen 's link is now dead too, but you can find it on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120115011942/http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=30-C-Tips-in-30-Days-Tip-28-the-lifetime-of-a-temporary-object-bound-to-a-reference).

Comment: Documentation on lifetime extension: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary

Comment: C++11 and beyond supports the use of rvalue references, which can be used like a normal reference variable. `A&& mySecondObject = myFunction()` should create a lvalue reference variable now. [Link about reference initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)

Answer (score 16):

It's possible with a const reference.

`myFunction` returns by value, so that return value is a temporary object. You can bind a temporary to a const reference, and the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference. You can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference (unfortunately).

The return value of `myFunction` might be a *copy* of `myObject`. On the plus side, copy constructor elision (aka the "named return value optimisation" in this case) permits the compiler to construct `myObject` directly into the temporary which is the return value of `myFunction`, presumably located somewhere on the stack of the calling code. If it does that, then when `myObject` goes out of scope the object is not actually destroyed. The optimisation is commonly implemented - for example GCC (usually?) does it even without any optimisation flags.

Copy ctor elision also permits the compiler to avoid all copying if you did:

```
A mySecondObject = myFunction();
```

This requires the application of both legal types of copy ctor elision: (1) returning a named value from a function, and (2) initializing an object from a temporary.

Comment: At the bottom of [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Lvalue_references), "...value references and lvalue references to const extend the lifetimes of temporary objects...", then references [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization), which lists as an exception, "...a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a return statement is not extended..." does that mean that it's UB even when it's a const ref because the ref refers to the return value of the function?

Comment: @jrh: no, that second link is talking about what happens if, inside a return statement, you bind a temporary to a reference. So for example `const int & foo() { return int(); }` is no good because you took a reference to the temporary `int()` and then bound it to the reference which is returned from `foo`. This fails to extend the lifetime of the temporary.

Comment: True. Fair point, a temporary return value has reason to behave differently than returning a variable on the stack. [FYI: (kinda old) Chat transcript for context](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/conversation/const-ref-to-return-by-value-function-return-value)

Answer (score 9):

You might be interested in the [return-by-value optimization](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.9) that many compilers make to avoid calling the copy constructor.

Comment: This is one of those ideas that I'm looking for. I can't visit the page but I believe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization would be similar.