# rvalue reference and return value of a function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, move, rvalue-reference

I am new to c++11 and have the following question while reading the [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#rval).

Suppose we have a function `f`() that returns a value in type `X`, then we have the following ways to store its returned value:

```
X a = f();    // copy assignment
X&& b = f();  // move assignment
```

According to [C++ FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#rval), the second one avoids an unnecessary copy.

My question is: is the second one always the preferred way to receive the return value of a function call?  In addition, is `auto c = f();` equivalent to one of the above assignments? Thank you.

Comment: See also [Why assign a return value to a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684646/why-assign-a-return-value-to-a-reference)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have labelled the lines incorrectly. Neither of them are assignments, let alone copy and move assignments respectively. Instead, the first involves copy/move construction (depending on if `X` has a move constructor) and the second is simply initialising a reference.

The preferred way to receive the return value of a function call is the first way:

```
X a = f();
```

The copy from the temporary returned by `f()` into the object `a` will almost certainly be elided. This is the same form that `auto c = f();` will take.

The second one should rarely, if ever, appear in your code. You are making an rvalue reference to the return type of `f()`. Stroustrup is only doing this to demonstrate that temporaries can bind to rvalue references. This occurs most often in real code when you invoke a move constructor/assignment operator, which have an rvalue reference argument type.

Comment: Oh yes, they are not assignments, they create things instead.  Thank you very much for pointing out my mistake and providing valuable answer!

Comment: So the second one won't save any operation (such as copy) at all?  Originally I thought the second one just simply takes that returns from `f()` without creating a new thing.  Can I know where I might wrong / miss here?

Comment: @keelar You're correct, there will be no copy. It just binds a reference to the object that is returned. But chances are, there will be no copy with the first either.

Comment: Thank you for further explaining this.  So why and how does the first case avoid the copy?  Does it rely on the implementation of `X`'s `=` operator?

Comment: @keelar Neither case uses `operator=` because they're not assignment. Nonetheless, the reason the first case would avoid a copy is because the C++ standard explicitly allows compilers to omit copies in certain cases (this is one of them). Look up copy elision.

Answer (score 5):

1. None of what you wrote is an assignment. All code pieces declare and initialize a new variable.
2. `auto a = f()` is the same as `X a = f()`
3. `X && b` is a reference, not an object.
4. Always create a local object variable, i.e. `X a = f()`, never an rvalue reference. There is (almost) never a good reason for the latter. In either case you get an object that lives for as long as the variable does, and there's no need for the additional complexity.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my mistake and providing detailed answer!