# Using local variable assigned to return value of a function or using function directly

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-construction

Is there a difference between this:

```
MyClass c = getMyClass();
calculate(c.value);
```

and this:

```
calculate(getMyClass().value);
```

in the scope of performance and memory allocation?

Comment: There might actually be a *semantic* difference, for example if `getMyClass` returns a reference the first invokes the copy constructor (RVO non withstanding) but the latter doesn't.

Comment: Is "easier to display the intermediate value in some debuggers" a significant difference for you?

Comment: Well, what i meant was what were the effects on performance and memory allocation ?

Comment: @Semih Kekül the first example uses `value()`, while the second example uses `value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a fairly serious difference. In the first case, `c` is an lvalue, and it will not be destroyed until the end of the scope. This can delay useful things like reosurce cleanup. More problematically, it being an lvalue means that it cannot be moved, but must be copied, which is inefficient for many classes but downright illegal for some very important classes, like `unique_ptr`.

In the second case, the compiler cleans up the temporary right away, so all resources are released promptly, and it being an rvalue gives the compiler more freedom to optimize and permits move semantics.

This is still true when `value` is a member or member function, as the result of both can inherit value category from their parent object.

You should always scope objects to the minimum scope required, and if you don't need to access `c` later, then you should use the temporary.

Comment: If `getMyClass()` returns `const MyClass&` and `MyClass::value()` is a `const` function (which may or may not be true based on the original question), can the compiler optimize the `MyClass c =` code so that no instance of `MyClass` is created? If so, does it make sense to say `c` will not be destroyed until the end of the scope? I'm trying to understand the text above in light of comments made elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a difference? Yes, massively so. To the reader.

The compiler couldn't care less which way you write it. The code emitted, space used and time of execution are so close they're not worth spending one millisecond of thinking time on.

But your readers will care. In some situations the first form offers the opportunity to provide a useful variable name to help explain your intent. In other situations the lack of a declared variable makes it a single statement and could be easier to read, especially if there are lots of them.

Please, get over the idea you should care about what the compiler thinks and start to care more about what your readers think! And, by the way, you are one of those readers in six month's time.

Comment: The compiler absolutely does care which way you write it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope! It merely evaluates the `getMyClass().value` expression and sends it to the method's parameter.
Of course, the parameter itself is a local variable scoped to the method.

Comment: Which will certainly be deleted in a non-debug compilation.

Comment: His unedited question was about whether some phantom local variable would be temporarily created for the expression at the 2nd option: `calculate(getMyClass().value);`. He wasn't concerned if it's deleted later!

Comment: Much less asked for scolding him for worrying about performance as you did @david.pfx!

Answer (score 0):

The first form tells the compiler to create a new instance of `MyClass`. If `getMyClass()` returns a `const` reference to `MyClass`, you don't really need a new instance. Your compiler may optimize the new instance away, but under those circumstances, if `MyClass::value()` is a `const` function, I prefer to write

```
const MyClass& c = getMyClass();
calculate(c.value());
```

Even if `getMyClass()` returns a simple `MyClass`, technically you can still declare 
`const MyClass& c`; the compiler will simply force the new instance of `MyClass` 
to remain in existence as long as `c` is in scope, similar to what happens if
you declare `MyClass c`, though there are arguments over whether this is a good
coding practice (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340925/return-by-value-assigned-to-const-reference]) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684646/why-assign-a-return-value-to-a-reference)).

As has already been pointed out, the instance created by the first form continues to exist until the end of the scope, although you can minimize the effect in this case by adding an extra pair of `{` and `}`:

```
{
  MyClass c = getMyClass();
  calculate(c.value());
}
```

Personally, in most cases I prefer to create a local variable with a name that tells me something about what I'm passing to the `calculate` function, to make the code more self-documenting.  An exception is when I have to call `calculate` several times in a row on different values, in which case it may be clearer what's happening if the calls occur on consecutive lines of code without declaring any new variables.

Comment: "the first form forces the construction of an additional instance of MyClass" It most assuredly does not. Eliminating such trivialities are well within the compiler's power.

Comment: Given the much more surprising things compiler optimization can do, I should have thought of that. I've removed the word "forces" and changed this to a style preference. Of is there a reason to write `MyClass c =` instead of `const MyClass& c =` when `getMyClass` returns `const MyClass&`?

Comment: By the way, regarding the consequences of the "`c` is an lvalue" objection, are those all things the compiler _can't_ fix, at least in the case where `getMyClass` returns `const MyClass&`? Because that objection was what made me think of the `const MyClass& c` thing in the first place.

Comment: If you want to mutate `c`? If the object referenced by `getMyClass` may be deleted soon? Besides, there is no guarantee that `getMYclass` does, infact, return `const MyClass&`. And yes, those are things the compiler absolutely cannot fix. It is a user-observable semantic, not an implementation detail.

Comment: Based on the original question, we don't know what `getMyClass()` returns, but in an actual programming environment you can usually find that out. As for mutating `c`--oops, I assumed `MyClass::value()` is a `const` function, which wasn't given. OK, made note of that too in the answer. But other than that, OP indicates no desire to mutate `c`. And if the value behind `getMyClass()` is so likely to disappear or mutate under us, I don't know if I even trust the results of `calculate(getMyClass().value)`. That seems a rather different question.