# Another c++ temporary lifetime confusion

Tags: c++

In the below code snippet...  is it safe to store a reference to the temporary string returned by `Quote::toXML` in `ToXML::s_` member variable, at least as long as it is used with the `<<` operator only?  I.e. is the result of the sub-expression `q.toXML` alive until the next `;`?

And what is the full expression here w.r.t. the return value of `q.toXML`.  The entire `std::cout` or the call to `ToXML` constructor ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct ToXML
{
    ToXML(char const * const tag, std::string const & s) : tag_(tag), s_(s)
    {
    }

    char const * tag_;
    std::string const & s_;
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, ToXML const & v)
{
    return os << "<" << v.tag_ << ">" << v.s_ << "</" << v.tag_ << ">";
}

struct Quote
{
    std::string toXML() const
    {
        return "<Quote/>";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Quote q;
    std::cout << ToXML("quote", q.toXML()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822243/store-return-value-of-function-in-reference-c
According to that information, since your function takes a const-reference it looks OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

From [class.temp]:

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. [...]
>
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.117 The temporary to which the reference is
> bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists
> for the lifetime of the reference except:
> — A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion
> of the full-expression containing the call.

We're in that bullet point. The temporary object is bound to a reference parameter (`s`) and persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call. That is, it persists until

```
std::cout << ToXML("quote", q.toXML()) << std::endl;
// --- here ---------------------------------------^
```

Since it lasts throughout its usage, it is perfectly safe. However, as soon as you do something like:

```
ToXML x("quote", q.toXML());
```

you're stuck with a dangling reference, so I would use this pattern sparingly.